# Git update to newer tag - How to?

Tags: git

I have cloned the DWM repository (http://dwm.suckless.org) and I want to use the stable version of DWM (currently 6.0) at all times. I maintain my personal changes in my a branch.

This is what I've done so far:

```
git clone git://git.suckless.org/dwm
cd dwm
git checkout -b mybranch 6.0
<apply cusomisations: several commits>
```

- Assuming my approach is correct so far, suppose version 6.1 is released and I want to update  to 6.1, how do I go about that?
- **Bonus question:** If I already have a branch with the newest changes (not stable), what would I need to do to revert (without rewriting history) to tag 6.0 and keep my own commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to another tag just:

```
git checkout 6.1
```

About 6.1 is released, do you need to merge changes or totally switching?

Comment: Do you mean that I should run `git checkout 6.1` in mybranch` after I've run `git pull` in master? I don't understand your question.

Comment: About the 1st point Yes. about the 2nd point, you asked "Assuming my approach is correct so far, suppose version 6.1 is released and I want to update to 6.1, how do I go about that?". so do you have a changes at you branch and you need to merge to the new 6.1 or you just need to switch to 6.1 and ignoring your updates?

Comment: I need to "merge to the new 6.1" (preserve my own commits).

Comment: 1st switch to 6.1 "git checkout 6.1" then merge the changes from your branch to 6.1 "git merge YourBranch". you may read this http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Instead of using a new branch, can't I create a new 6.1 branch from master and merge the changes from that branch into my existing branch?

Comment: I mean instead of creating a new permanent branch to use for my cusomisations, create a new temporary branch that I can delete after mergin the branches into my existing branch.